# Декодирование кириллицы в теле письма IMAP Python

Tags: python, email, imap, decode

Получаю письмо через imap таким образом:

```
term = u'"Письмо1"'.encode("utf-8")
mail.literal = term
result, data = mail.search("utf-8", "SUBJECT")
ids = data[0]
id_list = ids.split()
latest_email_id = id_list[-1]
result, data = mail.fetch(latest_email_id, "(RFC822)")
raw_email = data[0][1]
raw_email_string = raw_email.decode('utf-8')
```

Все содержимое письма содержится в переменной raw_email_string, выглядит она примерно так: "+97FPUox2GpmePqJG73mkhQigmUDDVDjJ4IKSWGNQ9eR/+NIRF8OkSMuZjUjBhzZ\r\nWm2yDhKoICVJwQ2ElfyIohw1Mch1JG9AroEQ8EmaolRBv/5nn+oxDBonu3ZXTww+8Xfh4mHIJ4uv\r\nwZIFioSA6RkmEJWESbS9VrjjLQUO0MjGjtlBNGjiAd7GSEZYgMAgo9u304eCAYScUAPRSsLkBHuL\r\nOtoQ3FFNcGiqEB0OrpIUQEJVJWVcz///16PJ/9Eu9xx03gGwbllQNJAHG2casSF5RKl0DRhXVaJe\r\nnpVkqfSmafRMvcOz5WvmbC2Y0vENOLNP31u4+P/vrKbT3K3iUwBUAMAVmUtBBDQPJJPJaNYu8pS0\r\ngd3EAixJ0BskNi2DjQfFCaT4cPp2UGyWeaRudXjyhrq6wJBo0rtvcABqXX/M/+NIRIIOyME22ikG\r\nBB0qMoZeAEwsVmH8piVOjm9HoyWbK6+eVCza5ZFE6il2PgVtThpIkHCE0ZSNLa5wVZdUlKH1nb4c\r\navombz6K22n/XeNfEKmkbQaAUcYA9p+JRZ5lwSMOYwNJFyQ1BZASUj1fTQ65QtJJ6ex4JNHCtKAs\r\nBWuqkYAnKAFP5g3rr4s6Gmxq72"

Из этих данных я могу извлечь только нужные цифры, например номер телефона из письма, но кириллический текст здесь закодирован. Скажите, как можно извлечь из этой кодировки кириллицу?

```
type(raw_email_string)
<class 'str'>
```

Так же, насколько я разобрался, данные которые мне нужны выглядят так: 
`=?UTF-8?Q?=D0=B0=D0=B7=D0=B3=D0=BE=D0=B2=D0=BE=D1=80=D0=B0?=\r\n =?UTF-8?Q?_10.07.2019_11:1?=\r\n =?UTF-8?Q?5:15_=D0=9E=D0=BF=D0=B5=D1=80=D0=B0=D1=82=D0=BE=D1=80_05?=\r\n =?UTF-8?Q?_=D0=9D=D0=9D`

Comment: Судя по виду и источнику - это `base64`. Попробуй декодировать, используя `base64.b64decode(s)` https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html

Comment: Я приблизился к решению с помощью этого: text, encoding = email.header.decode_header(raw_email_string)[0]
text.decode('utf-8')

но это декодирует только заголовок. Как декодировать тело письма?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сделать:

```
base64.b64decode(raw_email_string).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: выдает: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte

Comment: Мне нужно найти решение, которое раскодирует тело так же, как это выражение заголовок: 
"text, encoding = email.header.decode_header(raw_email_string)[0]
text.decode('utf-8')"

Comment: В вопросе показано полное содержимое `raw_email_string`?

Comment: нет, но содержимое содержит более 30000 символов

Comment: `print(base64.b64decode(raw_email_string))` что выдает?

Comment: b'\r\xe9b\xbd\xea\xdeu:"\xb6\xca)z\xb6\xad\xa2\xbd\xa0\x99\...' большую часть символов специально опустил.

Comment: Ты уверен в том, что в письме только текстовая информация? Без картинок и прочих вложений?

Comment: нет, там html содержимое из коротого я хочу декодировать кириллицу

Comment: Собственно там действительно `base64`. Вопрос в том, какая это `b'\r\xe9b\xbd\xea\xdeu:"\xb6\xca)z\xb6\xad\xa2\xbd\xa0\x99"` кодировка. Из проверенных стандартных - ничего не нашел. И судя по спецсимволам это не строка из вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

Ну, во-первых, это не base64 хотя бы потому, что встречаются два вида слэшей)

Поставьте imapclient

```
pip install imapclint
```

и затем попробуйте так:

```
from imapclient import imap_utf7
decoded = imap_utf7.decode(raw_email_string)
```

Comment: Обратный слэш в его примере это `\r\n` - перевод на новую строку. base64 это допускает. Плюс распаковка `b64decode(raw_email_string)` не вызвала ошибку. Но это не отменяет возможность работы вашего решения.

Comment: выполнил. Результатом получилась всё так же закодированная строка "/qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq\r\nqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq\r\n------=_Part_74299_1942540080.1562774643704--\r\n" - это конец строки

Comment: @АликсПлисов Ну судя по тому, что в конце, все окей. А вы уверены, что там должно быть что-то читабельное?